# Getting Client ip address without change software code

Tags: websphere, haproxy

We have haproxy and websphere in different machines to publish software. Software try to insert client's ip to database however it insert IP of haproxy. Programmers only use this code and they do not  change.

```
ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

I got tcpdump and i can see client's ip is on x-forwarded-for tag of http layer. Software does not use this tag to get, i think. Is there any way to change x-forwarded-for to remoteaddress? Is there any tips to get client's ip without change software code? What should i do in the websphere servers or haproxy layer?

Websphere version 8.5.5.11
haproxy version 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Well as websphere is a commercial product I would suggest to ask IBM which parameter should be set in websphere.

A short search in the Internet have bring up this page
[Potential WebSphere Application Server problems when deployed behind a WebSphere-aware proxy server](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/potential-websphere-application-server-problems-when-deployed-behind-websphere-aware-proxy-server) linked from this page [HTTPServletRequest.getRemoteAddr/getRemoteHost starts to return WebSphere Plugin host value from 8.5.5.16 or 9.0.0.11.](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/httpservletrequestgetremoteaddrgetremotehost-starts-return-websphere-plugin-host-value-85516-or-90011-0)

Tomcat have for this the [Remote IP Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve), I assume that websphere have a similar option.

I also strongly recommend to use a more recent version of HAProxy as the 1.8 will be soon end of live https://www.haproxy.org/ .